# List/map of loot findable near crash sites?

Tags: satisfactory

Each crash site has one crashed drop pod containing a hard drive, unlockable through meeting certain prerequisites. There are [lists of these](https://satisfactory-calculator.com/en/hard-drives) and [maps of the drop pods](https://drive.google.com/file/d/106Vd-yjX4TsPbXmou_HyZZvxq1w6kzmu/view).

But besides every crashed drop pod there's a bit of random parts scattered, often ages ahead of what's available to the player through normal progression (but more often just a mountain of screws and miles of wire) and I have yet to find a list of what is to be found where. Is there a list or a map of what can be found where?

List for Satisfactory update 5 is preferred, but if that is unavailable, any earlier will do (hopefully the changes won't be too drastic).

(on a side note - can one collect 50 plastic from the crash sites? [The Wiki](https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Crash_Site#Scattered_components) doesn't list any, but I'm nearly sure I've encountered some at one point, so either the wiki entry is obsolete/incomplete or I'm mis-remembering things.)

Comment: The [satisfactory wiki](https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Crash_Site) states that the components scattered around the pods are fixed as well.`All scattered items are fixed, including the amounts (e.g. two different games will have the same items in the same amounts, unless they are changed by a game patch)`

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica ...and that means answer to this question is possible. Obviously if they were randomized, such list would change from game to game. On a side note, the contents of the hard drives are random and only "latched" at the moment of start of research of the drive, so if you don't like any of the alt recipes you got you can return to a save >10 minutes earlier and re-research the same drive for a new set of recipes.

Comment: _there's a bit of random parts scattered_ - that's why I added that information. I didn't answer as I couldn't find a map or list myself.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the map over at Satisfactory-Calculator.com

https://satisfactory-calculator.com/en/interactive-map

If you're unsure of locations, I would recommend uploading your save file so it will display all your factory buildings on the map.

Comment: Unfortunately this only displays crash site locations, not what items are scattered around the crash sites.